Finding id of last child in table structure
I have DB structure like this one: structure.
message_id  from_user_id    to_user_id  subject    body    date_add    parent_message_id
1           1               2           message 1  body 1  2024-07-01  null
2           2               1           message 2  body 2  2024-07-01  1
3           1               2           message 3  body 3  2024-07-01  2
4           2               1           message 4  body 4  2024-07-01  null
5           1               2           message 5  body 5  2024-07-01  null
6           1               2           message 6  body 6  2024-07-01  null
7           2               1           message 7  body 7  2024-07-01  6
8           1               2           message 8  body 8  2024-07-01  7

I'm looking for efficient way to find last_message_id in each thread and total message count in each thread. If you have messages connected together with parent_message_id this create message thread (like in Gmail).
For example for:
message_id last_thread_message_id total_thread_count
1          3                      3  
2          3                      3
3          3                      3
4          4                      1
5          5                      1
6          8                      3
7          8                      3
8          8                      3

thanks for advice
R.

Can you define what "thread" is in your context?

Common recursive CTE will solve.

@SahapAsci I have updated problem description. If you connect together messages with parent_message_id this create some message thread.
Imagine you send message, someone reply to you to this message, you reply again, etc. This all message create one thread

I am not sure if its efficient but this is how I solve such "tree/hierarchy" problem.
WITH RECURSIVE 
message_tree(message_id, message_ids, hierarchy_level) AS (
  -- create a tree by using recursive CTE
  SELECT
      m.message_id,
      ARRAY[m.message_id]                   AS message_ids,
      1                                     AS hierarchy_level
    FROM message_tab m
    WHERE 
      m.parent_message_id ISNULL
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
      m.message_id,
      mt.message_ids || m.message_id,
      array_length(mt.message_ids || m.message_id, 1)
    FROM message_tab m
    JOIN message_tree mt ON m.parent_message_id = mt.message_id

   
),
agg_message_tree AS (
  -- filter tree, left only record with last message
  SELECT distinct ON (message_ids[1])
      mt.message_id     last_thread_message_id,
      mt.message_ids,
      mt.hierarchy_level
    FROM message_tree mt
    ORDER BY mt.message_ids[1], mt.hierarchy_level DESC
)
  --unnest aggregated tree to get all messages
SELECT
    unnest (amt.message_ids) as message_id,
    amt.last_thread_message_id,
    amt.hierarchy_level
  FROM agg_message_tree amt
  ORDER BY 1

fiddle here
